# Urls for Viewsets in Django Rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using Userviewset in Django Rest. I t provides all the functions : get, post,put,retrieve,delete. 
I have registered the viewset with router. And now I want to use POST method for creating new object. But I dont know any url. 
At what urls will be able to use these methods : POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE,DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably done something like this:
`router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)`
so your url is `example.com/users/`
after that you have to send the proper requests to that url
so:
`GET example.com/users/` will return the full user list
`POST example.com/users/` with a form of data will create a user object
`GET example.com/users/1/` will give you the user with id (if exists)
same logic for all the other requests
you should use a rest client to make your day easier
check "advanced rest client" extension for chrome